# How do I add durations together inn the same Google Sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to numbers formatted as 'durations' together using a formula in a Google Sheets cell. If it was two numbers it would be very simple...

`=1+2` would show as `3`

but if I do this...

`=00:10:00+0:20:00`, I get an `#error`

I've tried `=(00:10:00)+(0:20:00)` and `=DURATION(00:10:00)+DURATION(00:20:00)` but they also come out as `#error`. Looking around the docs and reference material I can't see how you handle durations in this way.

I know I could have each duration in two different cells and use a third cell to add them together but the way my Sheet is organised this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TIMEVALUE("00:10:00")+TIMEVALUE("00:20:00")
```

Format the resulting decimal as **DURATION**

Answer (score 2):

Using `TIMEVALUE` as suggested in [@TheMaster's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/111885/251080) will convert e.g. `25:00:00` to `01:00:00`.

If you **don't** want that sort of behaviour, but want the hours to continue counting beyond 24 hours, then you can also do:

```
="23:00:00"+"02:00:00"
```

If you format the cell as `DURATION`, then this will result in:

```
25:00:00
```